# Make OCaml Arg.parse function accept anonymous arguments starting with

Tags: parsing, ocaml

I am trying to use the `Arg.parse` OCaml function to read command line options and arguments, including not specified arguments starting with `-`. According to the manual:

> For the user to be able to specify anonymous arguments starting with a -, include for example `("-", String anon_fun, doc)` in `speclist`.

So I would expect this example to work:

```
let other_option x = Format.printf "Other option: %s@." x
let other_argument x = Format.printf "Other argument: %s@." x
let arg_speclist =[
 ("-a", Arg.Unit (fun () -> Format.printf "Known option: -a@."), "option a");
 ("-", Arg.String other_option, "any option")
]
let () = Arg.parse arg_speclist other_argument "Usage:"
```

With specified `-a` option and other arguments, it is working:

```
$ ocaml test.ml arg1 -a arg2
Other argument: arg1
Known option: -a
Other argument: arg2
```

But it is not when trying to use something starting with `-`:

```
$ ocaml test.ml -x
test.ml: unknown option '-x'.
Usage:
  -a option a
  - any option
  -help  Display this list of options
  --help  Display this list of options
```

I would expect the `other_option` function to be called.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the `("-", String anon_fun, doc)` doesn't allow you to do what you think, it allows you to type in options this way:

```
ocaml test.ml - -x
```

Basically, it makes `"-"` an "escaping" option that will pass the next one to anon_fun.

The exact behavior you want can't be done easily through `Arg` (which was never meant as an exhaustive complex argument parser AFAIK).

As a possible workaround, you may first manually go through your argv (don't forget not to read `0`) and to add options to your speclist dynamically:

```
let speclist = [ ("-option", Arg.String print_endline, "handled option") ]
let speclist =
 let r = ref speclist in
 for i = 1 to pred (Array.length Sys.argv) do
  let s = Sys.argv.(i) in
  if s.[0] = '-' && not List.exists (fun (s',_,_) -> s = s') !r
  then r := (s, Arg.Unit (fun () -> anon_fun s), "any_option") :: !r
 done;
 !r
```

Another option is to get the code from `Arg` and modify it according to your model, or to use another, more powerful tool. Maybe [`Cmdliner`](http://erratique.ch/software/cmdliner/doc/Cmdliner) is what you're looking for (I've never used it, so I don't know if it does the trick).